# Warlock Quest is to take life from another player, but I'm not allowed to attack them. Can I complete the quest?

Tags: talisman

We had a situation in *Talisman* 4th Edition Revised where a player got the Warlock Quest "[Take One Life From Another Player](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Take_One_Life_From_Another_Character)".

> "Seek the one with the mark of the Talisman - a mark that only you will see. When you find him, vanquish him in combat. His blood shall be your key. His suffering shall be your salvation."

The trouble was that the character wasn't allowed to attack another player. We were playing with the [Lightbearers](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Lightbearers) alternative ending that disallows player versus player combat, but this could also happen if, for instance, you are the [Knight](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Knight) and all other players are Good for the time being (or worse, they are characters like the Knight who are permanently Good), since the Knight can't attack Good alignment players.

Is there any way to complete this Warlock Quest if you can't attack other players?

Answer (score 1):

If the particular game scenario (such as Lightbearers) prevents any player-player combat, then the quest is never achievable, and the quest should be discarded and another one picked instead. However, if there is a possibility that a character could die and be replaced by another that could be attacked, then the quest should be retained against that possibility. That would be one of the risks of taking a Warlock Quest! Of course, your group could decide together to discard any unachievable quests and pick another.